# How to set Bitmap.Width and Bitmap.height

Tags: c#, image, bmp

Hi i have loaded a bitmap and i need to set my own height and width ,

```
bitmap.height = 100;
```

but this statement doesn't allow me because it says that

```
'System.Drawing.Image.Width' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

whats the method to re-size the bitmap? or assign these parameters ?

Answer (score 2):

The parameters are read-only because a bitmap is a fixed size.  Changing the size of the bitmap structure wouldn't do anything to affect the image.  What you need is to scale the image, rather than just assign a width/height property.

There isn't a built-in method I'm aware of that will do this for you, so you'll need to go through some extra work.  [This](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-image-editing-saving-cropping-and-resizing) tutorial may help you out.

Answer (score 2):

The other question will indeed help you by giving you some code. But you may want an explanation.

You can't assign to the dimensions because it wouldn't make any sense - once the image data is loaded, changing the size would require rearranging the data, inserting or removing sections of pixel data. A simple size assignment wouldn't have enough information to do this properly for you.

The proper way to change the size of an image is to create a new one, and then draw the old image onto it. For that, see the other questions that have been referenced.